# Program "gcc" not found in PATH with Eclipse CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt

I cannot seem to figure out how to use Eclipse CDT.

I am on Mac OS X, and am trying to print "Hello World" in C but I get an error:

> Program "gcc" not found in PATH.

What can I do to use C in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It may be because you don't have GCC compiler installed on your computer.

On OSX, you just have to open the Terminal and check `which gcc`. If it doesn't return a path, then [install GCC from here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer).

Once installed, this command should return the path :

[image: Looking for GCC in OSX Terminal]

I just had to restart Eclipse and everything worked well then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) on your machine

**update**
I would suggest following [this tutorial](http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/) to install brew. You can skip the ruby part if you don't need it.

Comment: No. I tried running CodeBlocks. Same error, I really want to set up Eclipse to compile with GCC Please help.

Comment: You need to add gcc to your PATH file. Go to terminal and type 'which gcc'  if it returns a location add that to your PATH file. Then restart eclipse.

Comment: `which`? it isn't `whereis`?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i got rid of it.

Install the MinGW.
Select all files in the Basic Setup and select apply the changes.
Select new C++ Project You will be able to see "MinGW GCC" in the toolchain section select the same and create project.

Comment: The OP is using Mac OS X, not windows.